# Is it acceptable to pimp your answers?

Tags: discussion

I was browsing through the [search results for 'evil'](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search?q=evil) when I came across [Is it possible to scientifically determine good and evil?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/357/is-it-possible-to-scientifically-determine-good-and-evil) Today, I asked [How could 'objective morality' be known/investigated?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/8506/how-could-objective-morality-be-known-investigated/8507), which seems to have some distinctive overlap. In particular, I suggested a science-like research project into objective morality. Anyhow, I have no idea about what is proper in terms of cross-posting (with edits) [my answer](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/8507/4556) into said good & evil post vs. just commenting and linking to mine, vs. doing none of the above.

Are there some general guidelines? I'm a systematic thinker, so I tend to tie a bunch of different closely related ideas together. I can see myself doing a bit of cross-linking of questions/answers (this doesn't seem to be supported all that well with SE, as tags don't always cut it), if that's kosher.

Edit: To clarify a bit, here's how the situation might seem to an outsider.

> Here is this guy, and he thinks his answers are awesome. He's referencing them from a several places that don't really seem to match the question. It seems like he is just trying to give his answers lots of exposure, to have more opportunities for upvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "pimping" your answers but you can use an answer of yours more than once if it actually answers a question more than once, but if you didn't modify it at all then technically it would mean the question is a duplicate  or your answer doesn't actually answer the question, which would not be allowed to persist (either the question (if a duplicate) or your answer (if wrong) would eventually be deleted).

- It's fine to link to other answers which others might find useful.
- If you ask a question with too much overlap with an existing question, it will be closed per guidelines.
- In general, we prefer quoting or rewriting relevant content rather than linking to previous posts, as they may get closed or deleted or changed in some way over time.

Does that help at all? I'm still not entirely sure what you're asking...

Comment: I think so, but please see my edit in the event that it clarifies things.

Comment: Well, your comments and references should be relevant. If they are not, they will be removed, that's all.